# Batch script for /f loop does not show all tokens

Tags: batch-file

I have weather.txt

```
January,Snowy,02
February,Rainy,15
March,Sunny,25
```

and main.cmd

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%M in (weather.txt) do (echo %%M %%T)
```

I expect output

```
January 02
February 15
March 25
```

But I get

```
January %T
February %T
March %T
```

Help THX

Comment: Why are you using `%%T`?

Comment: I thought %%T corresponds to the third token.

Comment: The third column is the second token, since you are skipping the second column so tokens 1 and 2 correspond to columns 1 and 3. The tokens have consecutive letters, so its `%%M` and `%%N`.

Comment: THX bro... i didn't know tokens have to have consecutive letters...

Comment: Based on your original assumptions that somehow letters represent a specific number, what would be the corresponding number be for X, Y and Z?  Also, the `FOR` variables can be UPPER CASE LETTERS and lower case letters.  They are case sensitive. And before you say you didn't know that, read the help file for the `FOR` command.  It literally explains all of this.

Comment: We would also appreciate feedback on your two questions you posted on DosTips.com

Comment: @Squashman to be fair, the `for /?` help text doesn't specifically say that the letters are consecutive (it just vaguely implies it), so the OP can be excused for not knowing that. But I still don't understand where he got the impression that %%T means third token.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you use `%%T` if you did a `for` in `%%M`.

cmd cannot assume a variable, they have to be in order. so for tokens 1 and 3 if you start with %%M you need the next alphabetical letter to display that token, not just a random letter. So therefore your code should be:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%M in (weather.txt) do (echo %%M %%N)
```